# Slow query performance and error troubleshooting - the 'where' clause is looking up a value in @Table on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that has multiple parts. I get certain information and put it into a table using `DECLARE @TABLENAME TABLE()`. I then have a query directly below which has a 'where' clause that looks like this:

```
WHERE a.PatientAccountID IN (
    SELECT Encounter
    FROM @TOC
)
```

In this query, @TOC.Encounter = A.PatientAccountID, so it is my understanding that this query will only look at encounters from the @TOC table.

This is not the case, so I am assuming there is a full table load going on and then the 'where' clause is being used. Am I understanding this correctly?

Should I instead put that 'where' clause in the JOIN above it? I know this is not working as I thought because I had to add:

```
AND A.PatientAccountID NOT IN (
    '12345678910', '99990000999'
)
```

to prevent errors.

---

I later changed the join to this (the error persisted):

```
FROM smsmir.sc_patientvisit                   AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN smsdss.QOC_vst_summ_v    AS B
    ON a.PatientAccountID = b.episode_no
        --test
        AND a.PatientAccountID IN (
            SELECT Encounter
            FROM @TOC
        )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN...
```

---

I have checked the `@TOC` table `Encounter` column. The offending numbers of `12345678910` and `99990000999` do not exist in that table. I have tried using

```
WHERE a.PatientAccountID IN (
    SELECT t.Encounter
    FROM @TOC t
)
```

*and*

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT T.Encounter
    FROM @TOC T
    WHERE T.Encounter = A.PatientAccountID
)
```

Both to no avail so far... Also strangely enough, when I do the following,

```
SELECT t.Encounter
FROM @TOC t
```

the offending encounter id's do not come out, but when I do

```
SELECT t.Encounter
FROM @TOC t
WHERE t.Encounter = '12345678910'
```

I get the varchar conversion error as `@TOC.Encounter` is of type `INT`. So I guess, as initially [indicated by Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771184/slow-query-performance-and-error-troubleshooting-where-clause-looking-up-value#comment57287388_34771184), my error lies there.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause pretty clearly limits the patients to those in the `@TOC` list (although the `LEFT JOIN` version doesn't).  Your problem lies elsewhere -- in the data in `@TOC` or in other parts of the query.  And, what is the error you are referring to?

Comment: I ran just the TOC table and did not see the offending encounter numbers so I now it's happening inside of the new table I am declaring TOCSummary where I have the where clause.

Comment: What is the actual question?  Are you getting incorrect results?  Is the performance bad?  Are you getting an error?  Different parts of the question suggest any or all of these.

Comment: The query peformance is slow and I am getting an error that conversion from the above varchar's is causing an overflow. I suppose I am really more concerned with the error and why when I specify which encounters I want I am getting the offenders as well.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator what are the data types of `Encounter` and `PatientAccountID`? What values are in `PatientAccountID`?

Comment: I give them a type of INT in my TOC and TOCSummary TABLE declarations - I also just updated the question to reflect further investigations.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator I'm still not sure what the data type of `PatientAccountID` is but in any case I updated my answer to include the conversion needed for when comparing the two columns.

Comment: They are VARCHAR from their respective tables, I am inserting them into temp tables with a data type of INT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT] Judging by the error that you are getting and the new information, it sounds like you also need to cast `PatientAccountID` to an INT when comparing it with `Encounter`. This can be done by using `CONVERT(INT, @Val)` or `cast(@Val as INT)`.

When using the `IN` clause with a subquery, the subquery will return everything, even if `a.PatientAccountID` was found, so yes you are right that a full table load is happening. If you want to minimize the table load then you could change it to an `EXISTS` like so:

```
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT t.Encounter
    FROM @TOC t
    WHERE t.Encounter = CONVERT(INT, a.PatientAccountID)
)
```

This would exit the subquery once a match is found, which makes this option the more appropriate choice for your fix.

As a side note you could also do an `INNER JOIN` on `@TOC` with a join condition matching `Encounter` with `PatientAccountID` like so:

```
FROM smsmir.sc_patientvisit AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN smsdss.QOC_vst_summ_v AS b ON a.PatientAccountID = b.episode_no
    INNER JOIN @TOC AS t ON CONVERT(INT, a.PatientAccountID) = t.Encounter
```

Comment: I am testing this out now, but you were reading my mind I was thinking of doing the `INNER JOIN` too.

Comment: @GordonLinoff From experience I noticed that changing my queries from using `IN` to an `INNER JOIN` helps with performance. But I guess I should of mentioned that the proper fix would be using the `EXISTS` clause instead.

Comment: @JohnOdom . . . I may be confused by the question itself.  I thought the problem is an error or incorrect results.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator I changed my question to indicate that using the `EXISTS` clause would be more appropriate to fix your slow query performance, but hopefully the `INNER JOIN` would also work for you :).

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE a.PatientAccountID IN (
    SELECT t.Encounter
    FROM @TOC t
)
```

One possibility is that the column in `@TOC` is not really called `Encounter` -- perhaps a slight misspelling. Without the qualified column name, SQL will take the field from a table in the outer scope -- and that field and the patient id might always be equal. That would explain the fact that no filtering occurs.

In any case, it is a good idea to always used qualified column names to avoid any confusion.

This is just an idea.

Comment: This situation could also happen, which would cause the performance to be dependent on the size of the `@TOC` table, but more importantly be a code smell.

Comment: I will give this a try, I did verify the column name of Encounter